# Resize Height Listview when Move button under ListView

Tags: android

In my app I have a listview and a button under Listview(button in footer listview or set under list in relative layout)
Now i want when i move button (up or down) height of listview will change.
How i do?
Thank for any ideal or solution!

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you are referring to a resize when you say move. For this, it is better to use a `LinearLayout` instead of a `RelativeLayout`.

Just set the `android:layout_weight` property of the `ListView` to `1`.

Example:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

When you do this, the `Button` will occupy the amount of space it requires and the `ListView` will take the remaining space and also scale accordingly.

Comment: my mean, when i click the button, hold it and move up and down, the size of listview also vary.Not problems with creating interfaces
Tks u.